# 2.4:1 aspect ratio

Tags: aspect-ratio, resolution

> Blu-ray Disc film releases may use only 800 lines of the 1920×1080
> resolution, resulting in an even 2.4:1 aspect ratio
>
> https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect_ratio_(image)#Previous_and_currently_used_aspect_ratios

If they use only 800 out 1080, shouldn't it be labeled 720p?

Answer (score 2):

**No.**

The picture being sent to the screen is 1920x1080, ie 1080p, even if only a portion of that contains usable picture. Your 800 lines are 1:1 pixel by pixel to your 1080p screen's native resolution.

720p is 1280x720, a whole lot smaller in both dimensions.
Transmitting 720p to a 1080p screen means the pixel ratio is no longer 1:1 & some interpolation is required.

Comment: so in that aspect ratio, do they also add the lines of the "black bars" for the total resolution of 1080p?

Comment: No signal, no information, black bars. Nothing is really 'added', as such, it's just an area of no signal data.

Comment: I still don't get it. How does the variable "pixel size" play into the equation then?

Comment: What makes you think pixel size is a variable?

Comment: The 1920x1080 resolution equals 2073600 pixels. OP seems to read that only 800 out of 1080 lines are used, so that equals 1536000 pixels. And you just stated "black bars don't count for pixels, no signal."

Comment: They don't count, because there's no information in them. They still exist. I'm really not sure what you're getting at now. It's still 'some pixels' mapped 1:1 to 'real , non-variable' pixels, on a screen with 1920x1080 resolution. This is, by no method of calculation, anything like transmitting an image of any dimensions, in 720p.

Comment: So for a 1080p resolution in 2.4:1 aspect ratio, how many pixels show real images (not black bars) ?

Comment: Why is this so important?? 1920x800 = 1,536,000. 720p, on the other hand is a mere 921,600… and you'd **still** have black bars, or a distorted picture. You're really going to have to properly explain exactly what it is you're trying to learn here. It gets less clear with each new comment.

Comment: Isn't this yet another pointless "I'm getting cheated out of pixels" question/rant?

Comment: @BCdotWEB - I'm not really sure any more. We started with "why don't they call it 720p?", which I thought I'd adequately explained… then we apparently took a sharp left down a cobbled alleyway & I've not caught back up yet;)